# cocoon gem not passing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

So although I have used cocoon successfully before, I'm still relatively new and for whatever reason can't seem to get it to pass through the parameters (I've tried with two different applications and on fedora 22 and mac 10.10.4).

For context I've been using the standard rails forms in .erb and have both :post and :post_items which only currently have a description.  I'm using cocoon 1.2.6.

So in application.js I have

```
//= require cocoon
```

in post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_items, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

  validates :title, :post_items, presence: true
  validates :title, length: {maximum: 255}
end
```

in post_item.rb

```
class PostItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

and my relevant controllers are (posts_controller.rb):

```
def index
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  params[:post][:ip_address] = request.remote_ip
  @post = Post.create(post_params)

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Your post was successfully created"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash[:failure] = "There was an error saving your post"
    render 'index'
  end
end

private

def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :tags, :hits, :ip_address, post_items_attributes: [:id, :description, :_destroy])
end
```

And finally in my views I have (_form.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for @post, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <p>There were <%= @post.errors.count %> errors</p>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <p><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
           <!-- a bunch of fields here -->
<div class="six columns">
    <h3>Add images</h3>
    <div id="post_items">
        <% f.fields_for :post_items do |post_item| %>
            <%= render 'post_item_fields', f: post_item %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Image', f, :post_items, class: "add-button" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "button submit-button" %>
<% end %>
```

and lastly _post_item_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f %>
</div>
```

There are CSS files that modify the html but I have no js other than what's automatically built. I've literally been stuck on this problem for days now and I can't figure out what's wrong.  I have tried the post.rb without the validates code but it still doesn't work.

The only lead I have is that when you print out the parameters it has already dropped the post_items parameters and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** for the sake of information I've added my migrations.

in db/migrate/20150722191917_create_post_items.rb

```
class CreatePostItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :post_items do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.belongs_to :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

and in db/migrate/20150722173629_create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :tags
      t.integer :hits, null: false, default: 0
      t.string :ip_address

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :posts, :ip_address
  end
end
```

Also if it matters I didn't use scaffold when generating them

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Also, is your post_items.html.erb file named correctly? It needs to be _post_items.html.erb to work as a partial

Comment: Oh yea I wrote the file names differently than I had them saved by accident; I'm going to edit the post quickly to contain the correct partial names I used

Comment: So the fields are showing up but not saving correctly?

Comment: yea so there are no errors, it just won't save the post_items to the post.  The pages otherwise load correctly and if I remove the validates it will create a post it just won't include the post_items.

Comment: I can also create post_items through the console so I'd assume the db is working

Comment: Do me a favor and try this.  Wrap the link_to_remove in a div and try it.

Comment: I did and it still didn't work; although the remove link was never a problem; the problem is the nested items won't save with the post.  (also the [docs](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) don't really require one)  Thanks for the idea though

Comment: I know cocoon relies on the view a lot. worth a try.  I'll keep digging, gimme a minute.

Comment: try renaming :description to :post_item_description in the database, controller, and view.  That worked for me

Comment: Also make sure post_items has post_id:integer

Comment: Thanks for the idea but still nothing; I'm going to try post_id now although it shows up in the console so I'd think it's added with post:belongs_to when the model is first created

Comment: yea adding it in manually only overrides the belongs_to method, so post_id is there regardless :/

Comment: do you have this in a repo? I'll have a look when i get out of work.

Comment: There isn't a repo; although I added the migrations if that helps

Comment: The one thing i noticed is you don't have `@post.post_images.build` which is required.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I finally figured out what's wrong (although I don't really understand what we're supposed to do to get around it) is that once I got rid of div class="six columns" it worked, so apparently that was interfering with the cocoon gems ability to parse the html.

Thanks everyone for all the help!

EDIT: to clarify I had to change _form.html.erb to:

```
<%= form_for @post, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <p>There were <%= @post.errors.count %> errors</p>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <p><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
           <!-- a bunch of fields here -->
    <h3>Add images</h3>
    <div id="post_items">
        <% f.fields_for :post_items do |post_item| %>
            <%= render 'post_item_fields', f: post_item %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Image', f, :post_items, class: "add-button" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "button submit-button" %>
<% end %>
```

So I guess it was a little my fault as the error would have been easier to spot if I had used the full html instead of parsing it for the cocoon-relevant bits but there it is regardless.  (basically the moral of this story is that you can't have div's inside of the form)

Comment: Few things: cocoon does not parse any html. Cocoon only helps in building the form. When posting a form, your browser will collect all fields inside the form, so if that fails I assume your html was not built correctly. Easily verified: what is posted to the controller, if it contains the fields you have strong parameters problem, if it does not, you have a html problem. Also: it is perfectly possible to use tons of divs inside a form. You cannot nest forms in forms though (pure html restriction). So just removing a single div cannot be the explanation imho.